# EKS volumesnapshot failing for PVC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, snapshot, amazon-ebs, kubernetes-pvc

I have dynamic PVC created with EBS volume which holds mysql. Now I am trying to create the snapshot of PVC using volumesnapshotclass and volumesnapshot. But the snapshot is not getting created. Below is my code:

Volumesnapshotclass.yaml

```
kind: VolumeSnapshotClass
metadata:
  name: test-snapclass
driver: ebs.csi.aws.com
deletionPolicy: Retain
```

Volumsnapshot.yaml

```
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: VolumeSnapshot
metadata:
  name: test-snapshot
  namespace: default
spec:
  volumeSnapshotClassName: test-snapclass
  source:
    persistentVolumeClaimName: mysql-data
```

It says snapshot has been created but I couldn't find any snapshotcontent and snapshot READY TO USE in false state.

Answer (score 0):

The CSI Driver needs to be installed after the volume snapshot CRDs and controller. Refer to https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/issues/1065